# Clickable graph nodes with NetworkX and Plotly

Tags: python, url, nodes, plotly, networkx

Currently I am developing a program that finds semantic links between international news and represents news with links as a graph. What I need is to make the nodes of this graph clickable, that means, when clicking on a node user should be redirected to a certain URL that is different for each node. Does anyone know the way to do it using NetworkX and Plotly? I have read the docs, on Plotly website there is only a "hover" option described, but there is nothing about on-click actions.

If making nodes clickable is impossible, I would like to get some advice on what to use instead of NetworkX and Plotly.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @BAC83 unfortunately no